# Openshift rhc setup "The OpenShift server is not responding correctly."

Tags: openshift, ghost-blog, openshift-client-tools

I would like to setup access to my open shift application. I have rhc client installed and wanted to run

```
rhc setup
```

I'm asked about providing server hostname:

> Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|

so I enter the hostname of my application: http://blog-trampkiwpodrozy.rhcloud.com

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error message:

> The OpenShift server is not responding correctly.  Check that 'http://blog-trampkiwpodrozy.rhcloud.com/broker/rest/api' is the
>   correct URL for your server. The server may be offline or misconfigured

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 22):

You need to accept the default server hostname, run rhc setup again and use openshift.redhat.com not your application url.

Comment: The thing is that I have already one application configured and when I don't pass the hostname the token for the other application is used. So any ideas how to configure the second application?

Comment: Re-run rhc setup, and use openshift.redhat.com.  You are probably inside the cloned directory so it automatically uses that application.

Answer (score 10):

In case you are setting up with openshift

Just press enter.(it will take openshift.redhat.com as input)

After pressing enter, you and get the option to enter login username & password, as mentioned in the Docs

Follow these steps:

https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html

Comment: Pressing enter without entering anything perfectly worked for me.

Comment: I was at my wits end